# Cannot read property 'uid' of null

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I've got my AuthService, where I subscribe to authState.

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    private user: User = null;

    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
       const sub$ = this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
       this.user = auth;
    });

   get userId(): string {
       return this.user.uid;
   }
}
```

Now in other component I want to take objects belongs to current logged user so I created a service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class SomeService{

    constructor(private readonly afs: AngularFirestore,
                private auth: AuthService) {
    }

    ...

     getByCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
         return this.afs.collection<any>('my-path',
            ref => ref
            .where('userId', '==', this.auth.userId)).valueChanges();
     }
}
```

And in component I subscribe to this method:

```js
...

ngOnInit() {
   this.getData();
}

private getData(): void {
   this.testService.getByCurrentUser().subscribe(
     res => console.log(res),
     error => console.log(error)
   );
}
```

**Problem**:
When I redirect between pages it's works fine, but after refresh page `getData()` method is called before `authState` callback assign current auth and in effect `userId()` method return null.

How to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an auth [guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication) or a [resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data), something like this:

This guard will prevent a route from being loaded unless the user is authenticated.

```js
export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.auth.authState.pipe(map((auth) => {
      if (!auth) {
        // Do stuff if user is not logged in
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }),
    take(1));
  }
}
```

Use it in your routing module:

```
{
  path: 'yourPath',
  component: YourComponent,
  canActivate: [AdminAuthGuard],
}
```

---

**Or** this resolver will set the current user id before a route is loaded:

```js
export class UserIdResolver implements Resolve<boolean> {
  constructor(
    private auth: AngularFireAuth,
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) {}

  resolve(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.user.pipe(map((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.authService.setCurrentUser(user.uid); // set the current user
        return true;
      }
      this.authService.setCurrentUser(null);
      return false;
    }), take(1));
  }
}
```

Use it in your routing module:

```
{
  path: 'yourPath',
  component: YourComponent,
  resolve: [UserIdResolver],
  runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
}
```